# Type mismatch: inferred type is Fragment but YouTubePlayerSupportFragment was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube-api

I keep on getting this error since I upgraded my Android Studio.
Here's my activity_main.xml (Relevant part)

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/youtube_player_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Here's my MainActivity.kt

```
lass MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    lateinit var youTubePlayerSupportFragment: YouTubePlayerSupportFragment
    lateinit var youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        initializeYoutubePlayer()
    }


    private fun initializeYoutubePlayer()
    {
        youTubePlayerSupportFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player_fragment) //<-- I get ERROR in this line

    }
}
```

Comment: Cast it to `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`. `findFragmentById` has a return type of `Fragment`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a cast operator `as` when setting `youTubePlayerSupportFragment`. By default `findFragmentById` returns an object of `Fragment` type:

```
...
private fun initializeYoutubePlayer() {
    youTubePlayerSupportFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player_fragment) as YouTubePlayerSupportFragment
}
...
```

An easier option would be to use your `Fragment` directly by its ID since it's defined in the xml file already:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //your Fragment is bound at this point
    assert youtube_player_fragment != null
}
```